# Can't play media file in Ubuntu

Tags: plugins, media

Whenever I try to play media file, it says "required plugins couldn't be found".....
I installed Ubuntu via flash drive...how can I install MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3) decoder?
I just installed Ubuntu and still am rookie at it.

Answer (score 0):

Install VLC media player...it has the most codecs for audio and video

sudo apt-get install vlc

OR

look for it on the software center

Hope it helps

Comment: Tried installing but VLC just don't get installed!! 